# linQ of selecting all rows of an excel file accepting null values

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

It is working fine for me to read excel 2007 using LinQ and openXML:

```
IEnumerable<String> textValues =
                                    from cell in row.Descendants<Cell>()
                                    where cell.CellValue != null
                                    select
                                        (cell.DataType != null
                                        && cell.DataType.HasValue
                                        && cell.DataType == CellValues.SharedString
                                        ? sharedStrings.ChildElements[
                                        int.Parse(cell.CellValue.InnerText)].InnerText
                                        : cell.CellValue.InnerText)
                                    ;
```

However, if one of my cells are null (blank). Then they are excluded in the textValues. How can I change the query in order to select all cells included blank values, I already tried this query:

```
from cell in row.Descendants<Cell>()
select cell.CellValue.ToString();
```

but I got this error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

How should the select query to be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
from cell in row.Descendants<Cell>()
select Convert.ToString(cell.CellValue);
```

`cell.CellValue` is `null` and you get the exception when calling `ToString()` on it.